# Running JSP Files On Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, eclipse-indigo

I used to work on Notepad++ for running my jsp applications . I am a newbie to jsp though !!
But my teacher recommended me to use Eclipse for jsp . So , I did the same . I installed Eclipse Indigo and added Web Plugin For running the jsp files . Now I have written some codes in jsp but don't know how to configure my local apache server with the Eclipse . Previously I used to paste the jsp files in the tomcat directory and run the files .

**Now Please help me on integrating my apache web server with my Eclipse Indigo !!**

Comment: See the link: http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/how-to-configure-apache-tomcat-in-eclipse-ide/

Answer (score 0):

Under eclipse you can go to Windows (Alt+W) >Show View > Servers.

When your server window opens,you can right click and then click add server, select tomcat version that you have on your system and then provide the path at which your tomcat is located, then just install it. You have your tomcat configured on your system.

You can start/stop your servers using and green and red button present in the server console that you first opened using Windows server option.

Hope that clears your question.